# AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'btn' error when running popup function on main window(kivy)

Tags: python-3.x, popup, kivy

Im trying to use the popup function in ScreenManager and in MainWindow and i got AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'btn' error. Can someone help me :( I know that if i remove the  and screen manager i can get it running but i need those windows for the future.Or is there any other methods to do this?

## windows.py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import kivy
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class Widgets(Widget):
    def btn(self):
        show_popup()

class P(FloatLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Widgets()


def show_popup():
    show = P()

    popupWindow = Popup(title="Popup Window", content=show, size_hint=(None,None),size=(400,400))

    popupWindow.open()

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kys = Builder.load_file("windows.kv")

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kys


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

## windows.kv file

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    Button:
        text: "Shutdown"
        on_release: root.btn()
        size: 75, 50
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'left': 1, 'bottom': 1}

<Widgets>:
    Button:
        text: "Shutdown"
        on_release: root.btn()
        size: 75, 50
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'left': 1, 'bottom': 1}

<P>:
    Label:
        text: "Are you sure you want to shutdown?"
        size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "top":1}

    Button:
        text: "Yes"
        size_hint: 0.8, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "y":0.1}
```

Comment: Please revisit your code and post a minimum running example. You are returning 2 App instances.

Comment: In your `kv` file you have `on_release: root.btn()` under your `MainWindow` rule. There is no `btn()` method in your `MainWindow`, thus your error.